# Can not start a job from java code in spark; Initial job has not accepted any resource

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata

Hello my Spark configuration in JAVA is :

```
ss=SparkSession.builder()
    .config("spark.driver.host", "192.168.0.103")
    .config("spark.driver.port", "4040")
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false")
    .config("spark.cores.max","1")
    .config("spark.executor.memory","471859200")
    .config("spark.executor.cores","1")
    //.master("local[*]")
    .master("spark://kousik-pc:7077")
    .appName("abc")
    .getOrCreate();
```

Now when I am submitting any job from inside code(not submitting jar) I am getting the Warning:

> TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

The spark UI is [image]

The worker that is in the screenshot is started from command:

```
~/spark/sbin/start-slave.sh
```

All the four jobs those are in waiting stage is submitted from java code. Tried all solutions from all sites. Any idea please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you wanted to run a spark job using only one executor core, you don't have to specify `spark.executor.cores`.

`spark.cores.max` should handle assigning only one core to each job as its value is 1.

Its always good practice to provide the configuration details like master, executor memory/cores in `spark-submit command` like below:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master spark://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7077 \
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --total-executor-cores 100 \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

In case **if you want to explicitly specify the number of executors** to each job use `--total-executor-cores` in your `spark-submit` command

Check the documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)